# Trigger HTTP fileupload by reading a file from another multi part HTTP request

Tags: node.js, stream, multipartform-data, busboy, nodejs-stream

An upload end-point receives data from a client in multipart file. This file is again sent as a parameter to new HTTP call made from the same service.

//Client uploading a file code

```
form(enctype="multipart/form-data", action="/data/upload", method="post")
  input(type="file", name="data")
```

I want to read that file and upload that to another Java end-point that accepts the file.

I tried getting the file stream via busBoy and converted it into a string and tried converting the string back into the stream and passed it to the new request. But this fails from Java service.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const FormData = require('form-data');
const { Readable } = require('stream');

const fileBufferChunks = [];

busBoyStream.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
  file.on('data', (data) => {
    fileBufferChunks.push(data);
  });
  file.on('end', () => {
    console.log(` ${filename} file parsed from req`);
    const fileString = Buffer.concat(fileBufferChunks).toString('base64');
    const data = new FormData();
    const readableStream = Readable.from([fileString]);
    data.append('file_param', readableStream);
    const headers = data.getHeaders();
    const axiosConfig = {
      method: 'post',
      url: URL,
      headers: {
        ...headers,
      },
      data,
    };

    axios(axiosConfig)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('job trigger success');
      });
  });
});
```

But if I store the file in local and pass the same file stream via *fs.createReadStream* it works.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');

const fileBufferChunks = [];

busBoyStream.on('file', (fieldname: any, file: any, filename: any, encoding: any, mimetype: any) => {
  file.on('end', () => {
    const data = new FormData();
    const saveTo = '/dummypath/name.csv';
    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
    data.append('file_param', fs.createReadStream('/dummypath/name.csv'));
    const headers = data.getHeaders();
    const axiosConfig = {
      method: 'post',
      url: URL,
      headers: {
        ...headers,
      },
      data,
    };

    axios(axiosConfig)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('job trigger success');
      });
  });
});
```

I want to understand what is the difference between the stream which is created converting the file to string and creating a stream from that file string and a stream created using fs.createReadStream(pathToFile)

Can anyone explain why there is a difference in behavior and what is the recommended way of sending file upload from one HTTP request to another request...?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the handling file properties with library [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) which converts streams to formdata specific payload.

[form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) library auto populates the contentType information of file if the stream is [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) generated file stream. So it was working fine with fs file streams. In my case the stream is Readable file stream from stream library so i need to manually provide the contentType information like below example.

```
data.append(uploadFile.fieldname, uploadFile.file, {
   filename: 'filename.csv', // ... or:
   //   filepath: 
   contentType: 'text/csv',
   // knownLength: 5,
 });
```

form-data library for handling files requires many file properties like this to be provides for custom stream objects. Full list can be found in their [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data).